# My Applications Are Missing in Finder>Username>Applications

Tags: macos

When I open finder and click on MyUserName in the sidebar I noticed that all my applications are missing.

When I click on 'Applications' in the side bar I can see them all and when opening the Applications folder from the deck they are there.

Why is this?

> System Version:   Mac OS X 10.6.7 (10J869)
>   Model Name: MacBook Pro
>
> Model Identifier:   MacBookPro6,2
>   Processor Name:   Intel Core i7
>   Processor Speed:  2.66 GHz   Number Of
>   Processors:   1   Total Number Of
>   Cores:    2   L2 Cache (per core):    256 KB
>   L3 Cache: 4 MB   Memory:  8 GB
>   Processor Interconnect Speed: 4.8 GT/s
>   Boot ROM Version: MBP61.0057.B0C   SMC
>   Version (system): 1.58f16   Sudden
>   Motion Sensor:   State:   Enabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OS X has two locations for applications to be installed.  The first is /Applications, or the Applications folder under the root of your hard drive.  The second is /Users/UserName/Applications, which is where you can install other software.  By default, the majority of Mac software will install into /Applications, which is why you see your programs when you click on Applications in the sidebar or open the Applications folder.

Long story short, you don't have anything installed in /Users/MyUserName/Applications, everything is in /Applications.

Comment: That is a very odd decision of Apples part

Comment: @TheLearner that's so the applications will be available to all users.  /Users/UserName/Applications is UserName's personal, private apps folder, so anything installed there is only available to that one user.  Actually, /Users/UserName/Applications doesn't normally even exist (to avoid this confusion), and if it's empty feel free to delete it.

Comment: @Gordon Davisson thanks mate, now it makes more sense